# PayPal IPN using personal account

Tags: paypal

I succesfully ised PayPals IPN service using this tut: http://www.infotuts.com/easily-integrate-paypal-payment-gateway-php/

I have it all working on the sandbox,
when I move it to live servers can I use my own personal paypal account as the merchant or is it mandatory that the merchant must be a business account?

Comment: Late answer, but took me a few hours to find this link.
You can use this link to configure IPN in your PayPal personal account.
It is missing from the new PayPal interface. [https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_profile-ipn-notify](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_profile-ipn-notify)

Answer (score 2):

According to the PayPal instructions the account must be either Business or Premier: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a business or premier account in order to create API credentials which you'll need in order to perform a redund. A personal account allows you to use an IPN when you use it via your button code.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you have Personal account , you can still pass the IPN URL from your button code and it should sent thru the IPN even if you don't have Business or Premier account .

Answer (score 0):

The working link as of 2023 is https://www.paypal.com/merchantnotification/ipn/preference

For me I converted my business account back to a personal account a few years ago without disabling IPN first. Now that the IPN URL is dead, receiving payments would send me an IPN warning email saying it failed. So as the IPN settings are hidden on a personal account I had to go directly to this URL to disable it.